# Resize like DropBox app in iOS

Tags: ios, dropbox, maximize

How to make resize function like DropBox app on iPad? 
when you open any file, you just double tap on the right side, then the file will be maximise.

how can I do like that?

Comment: See the [UIKit Animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1) reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use [QuickLook Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/filemanagement/conceptual/documentinteraction_topicsforios/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html)

It provide a `UIViewController` which can open any file (at least all those Dropbox can open), and already provide navigation / zoom like you need.